# how to display xml inside datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to read data from sql server database -It has a column of type xml. I have to bind the data to a label inside datalist as below

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <strong>PostedXml: </strong>
   <asp:Label ID="PostedXmlLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PostedXml") %>' />      
</ItemTemplate>
```

When the data is read, the tags won't display. Only values are rendering. How can we show the complete xml with tags on the label control?

thanks

Comment: Browser control instead of Label is better option to display xml.. Rest is your choice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be able to `Encode` the XML so it will render on screen tags-and-all.

Try replacing

```
Text='<%# Eval("PostedXml") %>'
```

With

```
Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("PostedXml")) %>'
```

Or if you're using VB, try this:

```
Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(DirectCast(Eval("PostedXml"), String)) %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an XML control 
`<asp:xml>` 
 that you can use instead of the Label, but it's requires the use of XSLT for formating.
Another option is to use the `<asp:Literal>` control or `<asp:Text>`, this will require the xml to be encoded.  Use the `Server.HtmlEncode`.